# Access Deny and Allow Functionality using Spring and Spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Currently I am trying to implement authentication example using spring MVC and spring boot with spring security. In my sample application what I am trying to do is - I am sending one authentication token in header of one URL. I need to take this authentication token from URL and decode. If username and password is matching , then only need to transfer the control to end point "api/getStudent/v1" or something like this. Otherwise from there only need to give the response that denying.

For this Currently I tried with authentication provider from spring security. But it is not suitable for taking the token from header of request. Here my confusion is that , from spring security which method I have to implement here ? Can anyone suggest a standard way of implementation ? Or Any documentation for this type of implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is create a custom security filter and plug this filter before spring security BasicAuthenticationFilter. Sample code -

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String authHeader = request.getHeaders("Authorization");
        //Decode the authHeader

        //Validate the authHeader with your username & password
        if(invalid) {
            //throw exception and abort processing
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Now either you can create the bean OR make this as `@component` so that spring picks it up and creates bean for you.

In your security configuration, add following -

```
@Configuration
public class CustomWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.addFilterAfter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know here if you are looking for any further implementation details.

Comment: This approach doesn't allow to apply this filter to articular endpoint only (e.g. api/getStudent/v1). Also, in this way authentication is not handled with Spring Security, and there will be no Authentication object associated with the current thread. Method level security (`@PreAuthorize` and `@PostAuthorize`) is not possible either.

Comment: @EvgeniyKhyst If order of filter is after `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` where this filter obtains existing security-context from the SecurityContextRepository. In the user defined filter it is possible to set Authentication object in to the security-context. So that your concerns about method level security `@PreAuthorize` and `@PostAuthorize` can also be fulfilled. In the custom filter, after validating header you can set auth object in to context as `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);` where your authentication object can have granted authorities.

Comment: @EvgeniyKhyst I am not sure why you have downvoted the answer. Regarding first point, we can always use spring security's authorizeRequests() with antMatchers() to define which endpoint is protected and which is not. Not sure why do we need to write so much code (which you have written) to define just this. Second, Though there will be no authentication object, we can create it pretty easily and pass around.

Comment: IMO, the answer is missing something like `if (invalid) { /* throw exception */ } else { SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication); }` and how to manually create this `authentication` object.

Comment: @Akash- Thank you for your response. This code is working. I am able to access and can deny and allow according to the result. Here I have one confusion , Within this `doFilterInternal()` method can I call one API ? Because my decoding and authentication is created as another API. Can I use rest Template inside this method ?

Comment: @Jacob You can do pretty much everything here what you can do in normal java class. You can also create a custom AuthenticationProvider and plug it with your security configuration. If you can post some clear example (what will be header etc.) what you are looking for, I can try to provide sample code.

Comment: @Akash - Yes. I already have one stackoverflow discussion on the same what I am looking for. Can you please check the link -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58950285/defined-property-from-application-property-getting-null-in-class-file-using-spri/58951265#58951265

Answer (score 1):

You can try out the following. I have used JWT authentication here. And as per your problem you can preauthorize  your end point "api/getStudent/v1" with spring's @Preauthorize annotation.
Following is the end point where user will be directed upon the signin.

```
@PostMapping("/signin")
public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginForm loginRequest) {

    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getEmail(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    String jwt = jwtProvider.generateJwtToken(authentication);

    UserPrinciple userPrinciple = (UserPrinciple) authentication.getPrincipal();
    String name = userRepo.findById(userPrinciple.getId()).get().getName();

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt, userPrinciple.getUsername(),
            userPrinciple.getAuthorities(),name,userPrinciple.getGender()));
}
```

Following is the **WebSecurityConfig** class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationRequestRepository<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest> customAuthorizationRequestRepository() {
        return new HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().and()
                 .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);



        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }


}
```

Following **JWTProvider** class includes the method to generate the JWT token.(note: I have set the email of each user as the username. You can do it according to your wish)

```
@Component
public class JwtProvider {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepo;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtProvider.class);

    public String generateJwtToken(Authentication authentication) {

        UserPrinciple userPrincipal = (UserPrinciple) authentication.getPrincipal();
        String name = userRepo.findById(userPrincipal.getId()).get().getName();

        return Jwts.builder()
                        .setSubject((userPrincipal.getUsername())) //getUsername returns the email
                        .claim("id",userPrincipal.getId() )
                        .claim("name",name)
                        .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                        .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET)
                        .compact();
    }

    public String generateJwtToken(UserPrinciple userPrincipal) {

        String name = userRepo.findById(userPrincipal.getId()).get().getName();

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject((userPrincipal.getUsername())) //getUsername returns the email
                .claim("id",userPrincipal.getId() )
                .claim("name",name)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET)
                .compact();
    }

    public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT signature -> Message: {} ", e);
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token -> Message: {}", e);
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Expired JWT token -> Message: {}", e);
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Unsupported JWT token -> Message: {}", e);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("JWT claims string is empty -> Message: {}", e);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser()
                            .setSigningKey(SECRET)
                            .parseClaimsJws(token)
                            .getBody().getSubject();
    }
}
```

Following is the **JWTAuthTokenFilter** class which is initiated in WebSecurityConfig class. Here is where it decodes the token from the rquest and checks whether the token is valid or not

```
public class JwtAuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtProvider tokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthTokenFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {

            String jwt = getJwt(request);
            if (jwt != null && tokenProvider.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                String email = tokenProvider.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);//returns the email instead of username

                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(email);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Can NOT set user authentication -> Message: {}", e);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return authHeader.replace("Bearer ", "");
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Following is the **JWTAuthEntryPoint** . Check **WebSecurityConfig** class for the use of this class

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthEntryPoint.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException e) 
                                 throws IOException, ServletException {

        logger.error("Unauthorized error. Message - {}", e.getMessage());
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Error -> Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

Following is the class I created for the constraints

```
public class SecurityConstraints {
    public static final String SECRET = "********";//add any secret you want
    public static final long EXPIRATION_TIME = 864_000_000L;
}
```

Comment: Please do ask for any clarifications

Comment: Did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you are working with REST API, you can use JWT and Custom Filter similar to this (https://medium.com/@hantsy/protect-rest-apis-with-spring-security-and-jwt-5fbc90305cc5)

Comment: Yes. I went through the documentation that you shared the link. But it uses user details and authentication receiving not in header. Here I want the auth token in header and need to implement the authentication. can you look on this? Correct me sir  if went in wrong direction please ?.

Comment: Hmm, what about using a custom filter (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter), and you can read the header by `HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    Enumeration<String> headerNames = httpRequest.getHeaderNames();` in `doFilter()`

Answer (score 0):

> I am sending one authentication token in header of one URL. I need to
>   take this authentication token from URL and decode. If username and
>   password is matching...

Usually, the goal of using tokens for authentication is to get rid of username and password check.

Basic HTTP authentication that is supported by Spring Security out of the box assumes passing base64 encoded username and password in the HTTP header: e.g. `Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l` (base64 encoded `Aladdin:OpenSesame`).

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/public").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
          .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

If you still need to extract username and password from a token in a different way, consider the following example.

Considering you have the following REST controller:

```
@RestController
public class TestRestController {

    @GetMapping("/api/getStudent/v1")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }

    @GetMapping("/info")
    public String test() {
        return "Test";
    }
}
```

In order to make endpoint `/api/getStudent/v1` protected and `/info` public, and extract principal and credentials from the HTTP request header you need to implement custom [`AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html):

```
public class HeaderUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    public HeaderUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(RequestMatcher requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher) {
        super(requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher);
        setAuthenticationSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
        });
        setAuthenticationFailureHandler((request, response, exception) ->
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, exception.getMessage()));
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        String token = request.getHeader("token");
        String username = token; //get username from token
        String password = token; //get password from token
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authenticationToken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

This filter must extract principal and credentials from the token passed in header and attempt an authentication with Spring Security.

Next, you have to create an instance of this custom filter and configure Spring Security to add the filter in the security filter chain (`.addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)`):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public HeaderUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        HeaderUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter =
                new HeaderUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**"));
        authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        return authenticationFilter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .addFilterBefore(
                        authenticationFilter(),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    //...
}
```

It is important to make the filter aware of the Spring Security [`authenticationManagerBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#authenticationManagerBean--): `authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());`.

You can configure what endpoints to protect with aunthentication by passing a [`RequestMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/RequestMatcher.html): e.g. `new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**")`.

For testing, you can create in-memory [`UserDetailsService`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) and test user with username `test`, password `test` and authority `admin`:

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    //...

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("test")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("test"))
            .authorities("admin");
    }
}
```

Run the application and try to access the public endpoint without an authentication:

```
curl -i http://localhost:8080/info
HTTP/1.1 200 
Test
```

the protected endpoint without an authentication:

```
curl -i http://localhost:8080/api/getStudent/v1 
HTTP/1.1 401
```

the protected endpoint without an invalid token:

```
curl -i http://localhost:8080/api/getStudent/v1 -H 'token: not_valid'
HTTP/1.1 401
```

and finally the protected endpoint with a valid token:

```
curl -i http://localhost:8080/api/getStudent/v1 -H 'token: test'
HTTP/1.1 200 
Hello, World!
```

Comment: I think you forgot OP is dealing with stateless requests where there is no session is associated with each requests. Your implementation of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and implementation of authentication success handlers for rest API looks like making simpler things more complex. For  stateless requests simple filter (`OncePerRequestFilter` impl of order before BasicAuthFilter) which reads token from header and sets authentication object to context or denies access is enough.

Comment: In the question it's mentioned: "If username and password is matching". Spring Security standard mechanism for this are `DaoAuthenticationProvider`, `UserDetailsService` and `PasswordEncoder`.

Comment: No token based authentication standards encourage sending password in token, in fact BasicAuthentication is an exception but it is a standard protocol supported by browser and it uses base64Encoder to encode, but the fact is that BasicAuthentication falls into different category where a application user only can undergo authentication process. & for token based/stateless authentication it is not required all processes which is done by `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` where it performs creating a session in background you may need to take of even that too, and successhandler not required.

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. Let me try this code. Now I just only tried the simple code given by Akash. That is working. Let me try to add your code. Its lengthy code. Let me add.