# Defined Property from Application.property getting NULL in class file using Spring boot Filter Implementation

Tags: spring-boot, properties

I am trying to do one sample of rest template and property injection for variable defined from application.property. For this I created one filter implementation and done like the following. But when I am accessing the property I am getting  error like following

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI must not be null
```

And I created my filter implementation code like the following,

```
@Component
public class  CustomSecurityFilter  extends  OncePerRequestFilter implements Filter{

@Value ("${securityTriggerServiceApiUrl}" )
public String triggerUrl;


 @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String authHeaderToken = request.getHeader("authToken");
        System.out.println("token :"+authHeaderToken);
        if(checkAuthenticationByAuthToken(authHeaderToken)) 
            {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        else
            {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            }
    }
 private static HttpHeaders getApiHeaders(){
        String plainCredentials="${seccurityTriggerEncodingCredential}";
        String base64Credentials = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredentials.getBytes()));

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        return headers;
    }

    public Boolean checkAuthenticationByAuthToken(String authTokenRequest) {

        AuthorizationRequest authApiRequestObj = new AuthorizationRequest();
        authApiRequestObj.auth_token = authTokenRequest;

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 
        HttpEntity<Object> request = new HttpEntity<Object>(authApiRequestObj, getApiHeaders());
        AuthorizationResponse authorizationResponseObj = restTemplate.postForObject(getApiTriggerStringUrl(), request, AuthorizationResponse.class);

        System.out.println("RoleId is :"+authorizationResponseObj.role_id);
        if(authorizationResponseObj.role_id >= 0 ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getApiTriggerStringUrl() {
        return this.triggerUrl;
    }
}
```

My application.property file added like the following,

```
seccurityTriggerEncodingCredential=test:test
securityTriggerServiceApiUrl=http://localhost:8065/test/security/authorizeUser
```

My Security config file contains like the following way,

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .addFilterAfter(new CustomSecurityFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}
```

Why I am getting the error like this?

Comment: If the value is `null` your filter isn't registered as abean, but just created with `new` instead of from an `@Bean` method.

Comment: Can you confirm how your filter is registered in your configuration?

Comment: @Akash - I used addFilterAfter method. I updated in my question. That is my config file look like.

Comment: As @M.Deinum mentioned, this is where the problem is. While registering filter, you have created a new filter. Configuration is not picking up the filter created by spring. There are two ways to solve this. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is while registering your filter, you have created a new filter with `new`. So configuration is not picking the one created by Spring. You can do either of following -

1) Autowire the existing spring bean in your configuration class -

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomSecurityFilter customSecurityFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .addFilterAfter(customSecurityFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}
```

You can do autowiring any way either directly through `@Autowired` or through constructor.

2) Second way is to create CustomSecurityFilter bean by yourself. Sample code as per your code -

a) Don't annotate your filter with `@Component`. Remove `@Value` and create a setter for your property.

```
public class  CustomSecurityFilter  extends  OncePerRequestFilter implements Filter{


public String triggerUrl;

public void setTriggerUrl(String triggerUrl) {
    this.triggerUrl = triggerUrl;
}

 @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String authHeaderToken = request.getHeader("authToken");
        System.out.println("token :"+authHeaderToken);
        if(checkAuthenticationByAuthToken(authHeaderToken)) 
            {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        else
            {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            }
    }
 private static HttpHeaders getApiHeaders(){
        String plainCredentials="${seccurityTriggerEncodingCredential}";
        String base64Credentials = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredentials.getBytes()));

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        return headers;
    }

    public Boolean checkAuthenticationByAuthToken(String authTokenRequest) {

        AuthorizationRequest authApiRequestObj = new AuthorizationRequest();
        authApiRequestObj.auth_token = authTokenRequest;

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 
        HttpEntity<Object> request = new HttpEntity<Object>(authApiRequestObj, getApiHeaders());
        AuthorizationResponse authorizationResponseObj = restTemplate.postForObject(getApiTriggerStringUrl(), request, AuthorizationResponse.class);

        System.out.println("RoleId is :"+authorizationResponseObj.role_id);
        if(authorizationResponseObj.role_id >= 0 ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getApiTriggerStringUrl() {
        return this.triggerUrl;
    }
}
```

b) Your configuration class will be then -

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .addFilterAfter(customSecurityFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

   @Bean
   public CustomSecurityFilter customSecurityFilter() {
       CustomSecurityFilter customSecurityFilter = new CustomSecurityFilter();
       customSecurityFilter.setTriggerUrl(<property value>);
       return customSecurityFilter;
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This answer is perfect one. I tried this way and now its working.